# How to append each XML tag next to each other

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

I am working on a scrolling marquee for election night that will fetch data and put it in order like the following:

**Town Name - Office Name - Canidate Name - Votes**

Right now it is putting all the town names, then all the office names, then all candidate names, then all votes.

**Jquery**

```
        $(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://vtelectionresults.sec.state.vt.us/rss/2713/ResultsData.xml',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).each(function()
  {
      var townname = $(this).find('TownName').text() + ' - ';
      var officename = $(this).find('OfficeName').text() + ' - ';
      var name = $(this).find('Name').text() + ' - ';
      var votes = $(this).find('Votes').text() + ' - ';


      $("#marquee").append(townname + officename + name + votes);

      }); 
      $('#marquee').marquee({ duration: 20000});    

}
```

XML:
https://vtelectionresults.sec.state.vt.us/rss/2713/ResultsData.xml

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/fq4ujyy2/

How Can I make it so it shows Town Name - Office Name - Canidate Name - Votes?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with RSS?  What is the question?

Comment: How can I make it so it shows Town Name - Office Name - Canidate Name - Votes  v.s. all the town names all the office names ect.... Thanks!

Comment: Show the XML please

Comment: https://vtelectionresults.sec.state.vt.us/rss/2713/ResultsData.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your }); character that ends your each loop before you call the marquee method.

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
  $(xml).each(function()
  {
      var townname = $(this).find('TownName').text() + ' - ';
      var officename = $(this).find('OfficeName').text() + ' - ';
      var name = $(this).find('Name').text(); + ' - '
      var votes = $(this).find('Votes').text(); + ' - '

   $("#marquee").append(`<p> ${townname} ${officename} ${name} ${votes} </p>`);
    });
      $('#marquee').marquee({ duration: 20000 });
}
```

Comment: hey borbesaur, thanks for the response, I tried but it is still showing all town names then all office names ect. I think this is on the right track though!

Comment: I took the time to look at the XML file you are hitting with AJAX.  As I understand it, .find will return the first match, so your logic looks good. The only thing I could think of is to group the string you are appending into an html tag together (as reflected in my edit).  The problem must be something to do with the #marquee div maybe the CSS? - that's all I can imagine.  Wish I could be of more help